# How can I obtain the right result from this recursive function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In the next function, I'm trying to return the number of ways you can construct a word: `target` using a list of parts of the word: `word_bank`.

I'm having quite a hard time figuring out why it doesn't return the right answer:

```
def count_construct(target, word_bank):

    if target == '':
        return 1

    total_count = 0

    for prefix in word_bank:
        if target.startswith(prefix):
            new_target = target.replace(prefix, '')
            num_ways = count_construct(new_target, word_bank)
            total_count += num_ways

    return total_count

print(count_construct('enterapotentpot', ['a', 'p', 'ent', 'enter', 'ot', 'o', 't']))  # answer: 4
```

The correct answer should be `4`, but at this point, it returns `1`.

For the next test cases it works perfectly fine:

```
print(count_construct('purple', ['purp', 'p', 'ur', 'le', 'purpl']))                    # answer: 2
print(count_construct('abcdef', ['ab', 'abc', 'cd', 'def', 'abcd']))                    # answer: 1
print(count_construct('skateboard', ['bo', 'rd', 'ate', 't', 'ska', 'sk', 'boar']))     # answer: 0
```

I would really appreciate it if someone helps me out figuring out what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: ``new_target = target.replace(prefix, '')`` replaces *all* occurrences of ``prefix``. Use ``new_target = target[len(prefix):]`` instead.

Comment: Thank you so much @MisterMiyagi it makes complete sense.

Answer (score 0):

@MisterMiyagi kindly added the answer in the comments, I'm adding it here to resolve the question:

`new_target = target.replace(prefix, '')` replaces all occurrences of `target`. Use `new_target = target[len(prefix):]` instead.